# Any specific idea why I cannot click on form fields on landing page

Tags: php, forms

I had a landing page designed and cannot reach the original developer.  For some reason I cannot click on the form fields.  Google search says that more than likely it is because an overlapping block or margin but I don't know enough to figure out which one it might be.

http://selldfwhomenow.com/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Your container element has a negative z-index placing it behind the body, removing the z-index should fix the problem.

Comment: +1 Tested the theory and the fields became selectable.

Comment: Thank you you.  I just discovered that as well.  That seems almost absurd to have missed that. Thank you.